# How to prevent mouse clicks from passing through GUI controls and playing animation in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Description

Hi Guys need your help I faced problems with mouse clicks which pass through UI panel in Unity, that is, I have created pause menu and when I click Resume button, the game gets unpaused and the player plays Attack animation which is undesirable.What I want is when I click Resume button, Attack animation should not be played. The same problem if I just click on panel not necessarily a button and the more I click on UI panel the more Attack animation is played after I exit pause menu. Moreover, I have searched for solutions to this issue and was suggeted to use event system and event triggers but since my knowledge of Unity is at beginner level I could not properly implement it. Please guys help and sorry for my English if it is not clear)) Here is the code that I use:

## The code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public static bool IsPaused = false;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
    public GameObject Player;
    private bool state;

    private void Update() {
        //When Escape button is clicked, the game has to freeze and pause menu has to pop up 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
            if (IsPaused) {
                Resume();
            }
            else {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }

    //Code for Resume button
    public void Resume() {
        //I was suggested to use event system but no result Attack animation still plays once I exit pause menu
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().ResetTrigger("Attack");
        }
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        IsPaused = false;
    }

    //this method is responsible for freezing the game and showing UI panel
    private void Pause() {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        IsPaused = true;
    }

    //The code for Quit button
    public void QuitGame() {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where/How do you start the attack?

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if i understood your problem, but it sounds like somewhere in your code you start an attack when the player does a left click.

Now your problem is that this code is also executed when the player clicks on a UI element, for example in this case the Resume button?

You tried to fix this problem, by resetting the attack trigger of the animator, i think it would be a better solution to prevent the attack from starting instead of trying to reset it later.

EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() returns true if the mouse is over an UI element.

So you can use it to modify your code where you start your attack:

```
... add this check in your code where you want to start the attack
if(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() == false)
{
// add your code to start your attack
}
...
```

Now your attack will only start if you are not over a UI element

Comment: Thank you a lot "R1PFake" that you decided to help and yes your solution worked perfectly. Thank you again))